# No se puede eliminar tabla de Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite3

Quiero asegurarme de eliminar una tabla (si existe) antes de crear otra tabla con el mismo nombre. Pero esto no ocurre, me doy cuenta porque hago cambios en el código y mando a compilar y ejecutar, y sólo noto los cambios (lo que me indica que se creó la nueva tabla) cuando desinstalo la aplicación previamente.

```
package net.eqsoft.pacienteapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class PacienteSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   String sqlDrop = "drop table if exists registro";
   String sqlCreate = "create table registro (reg integer, familiar text)";
   String sqlIniciar = "insert into registro (reg, familiar) values (2, 'none')";

   public PacienteSQLiteHelper(Context context, String nombre, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, nombre, factory, version);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase pacientedb) {
       pacientedb.execSQL(sqlDrop);
       pacientedb.execSQL(sqlCreate);
       pacientedb.execSQL(sqlIniciar);
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase pacientedb, int versionAnterior, int versionNueva) {
       pacientedb.execSQL("drop table if exists registro");
       onCreate(pacientedb);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno encontré la solución después de dar unas cuantas vueltas, este problema seguro es común. Cada vez que compilaba y ejecutaba la aplicación, ya había una base de datos creada con el mismo nombre de aquella que quería crear, por tanto ninguna de la órdenes: Drop, Create, Insert; posteriores se llegaban a procesar.

La Solución es borrar la base de datos al momento de la instalación de la aplicación basta con: context.deletedatabase("namedatabase").

Answer (score 0):

Después de la primera ocasión, siempre vas a tener un bd creada hasta que ejecutes el método onUpgrade(), asi que puedes llamar este método cuando instalas una nueva aplicación :

```
 @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase pacientedb, int versionAnterior, int versionNueva) {
       pacientedb.execSQL("drop table if exists registro");
       onCreate(pacientedb);
   }
```

Se puede usar `context.deletedatabase()` aunque la aplicación debería usar el método anterior.

me parece que lo que deseas es relacionado a pruebas y lo que generalmente se realiza es ir a la aplicación y borrar los datos o el cache, con eso aseguras eliminar la base de datos.

[image]

Comment: Hola, tenía el método onUpgrade, igual no me funcionaba, y creo que porque como android detectaba que ya había una base de datos idéntica omitiía todos métodos de la clase. Entonces en estos casos me parece que no hay de otra que prevenir con un borrado de la base de datos previa.

Comment: Si llamas correcamente onUpgrade() dentro realiza un DROP de la tabla registro    y realiza la creación nuevamente de la misma   con       onCreate(pacientedb); , creo que debería funcionar. saludos!

Comment: El borrado de caché y la instalación funciona bien, lo probé, claro que demoraba un poco más, Pero me imagino el caso en que un usuario desinstala la aplicación y luego la vuelve a instalar. ¿Cómo se podría controlar esto con el Upgrade?